# We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value, Pm2 3.5 error

Tags: node.js, pm2

We couldn't find uptime from */proc/uptime*, using `os.uptime()` value, Pm2 3.5 error

```
2020-02-11T20:11:43: PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value
2020-02-11T20:12:13: PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value
2020-02-11T20:12:43: PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value
2020-02-11T20:13:13: PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value
2020-02-11T20:13:43: PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value
2020-02-11T20:14:13: PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value
2020-02-11T20:14:43: PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value
2020-02-11T20:15:43: PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value
2020-02-11T20:16:13: PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have bulletproof evidences but same error started in our project when we updated PM2 from 4.2.3 to 4.4
To be honest, we installed module on host with internet and just copied it to production, this worked many times but it is anyway a bad practice.
So, after downgrade to 4.2.3 (installed correctly via Nexus) everything works fine